# what's wrong with my usage of UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I want to use `UINavigationController` in my application, my usage is as following:

1) In my root `view`'s .h file I declare a `navController` by:

```
UINavigationController *navController;
```

2) In my root view's .m file, I init the `navController` by (in `viewDidLoad`):

```
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
```

3) In my root `view`'s .m file, I add a handler to hander the button click event and in the event handler I try to present another view by:

```
WBSDKTimelineViewController *controller = [[WBSDKTimelineViewController alloc] initWithAppKey:kWBSDKDemoAppKey appSecret:kWBSDKDemoAppSecret];
[navController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

After that the `view` is't presented in the screen, nothing happened, I am sure my code are executed, what's wrong of my usage? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your root's view controller should be already wrapped within an `UINavigationController`. Then `UIViewController` has a property `navigationController` to access this `UINavigationController` and push/pop other view controllers to the stack.